# JSON schema described by the values in a common model instead of the names defined in the schema

Tags: json

I am recommending to my client the use of a simplified data schema where the core document exchanged between parties via api has static mandatory information captured with `identifiers`, `references`, `parties`, `dates`, etc. and then has flexible objects within an array which can capture any data value which has taxonomy based metadata to describe what the value is.

The alternative method my client is considering, blows my mind. They are considering committing every piece of collected data to the schema with a self-describing value name.

We're talking about an insurance company - for liability and property cover types, there are over 300 questions between them. If this was a spreadsheet, that's a lot of columns. If a customer was only requesting property, then only 175 of those questions would be used and either the remainder are optional or null values.

What I'm proposing is, an example document received from a broker:

```
{
 "characteristics" [
     {
         "category" : "business-activities",
         "type" : "activities-hot-work",
         "value" : "true"
     },
     {
         "category" : "business-employees",
         "type" : "employees-full-time",
         "value" : "6"
     }
     ]
}
```

Also, we could have another version of this document held at the API layer which uses the same categories and types but has the validation rules for the values received.

Example of validation version of the payload:

```
 {
 "characteristics" [
     {
         "category" : "business-activities",
         "type" : "activities-hot-work",
         "validation" : [
              "value_type" : "boolean", "mandatory" : true
              ]
     },
     {
         "category" : "business-employees",
         "type" : "employees-full-time",
         "validation" : [
              "value_type" : "integer", "mandatory" : true
              ]
     }
     ]
}
```

I would hope that using the two docs, the validation of resolving values to verification rules should be quite simple.

Is my logic making sense? What I want is to make the extending of what values are acceptable to receive to be a data management exercise instead of a new schema to be upgraded by all producers and consumers of a payload.

Additionally, I only want to receive the data I need for my request. I want the schema to be lightweight and flexible. I believe the schema does not need to be a flat version of an insurance product and every possible combination of questions.

I am thankful for your advice !

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: @ObsidianAge is there anything I could do better or its good bare bones?